# presentViewController with unwind/dismiss view controller animation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

Currently my storyboard is as follows:

Welcome->Login->Main

Login is displayed using the default cover vertical transition.
Instead of presenting Main the same way I would like to use the dismiss transition.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this by changing the arrangement of your controllers. The problem with this approach is that it leaves the first two controllers (which should be temporary) in memory after you go to Main, and it would be better to have them be deallocated, when you go to Main and start the normal workflow of your app. So, I would make Main the root view controller of the window, but present Welcome (modally) from its viewDidAppear method (with no animation), so Welcome will appear first. Then present Login from Welcome, and when you want to go to Main, dismiss both modal controllers from Login with:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. The only thing I would change is use [super viewWillAppear:NO] and an Unwind segue.